# MobX - updating a computed array updates the list component and all the list items as well

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react, mobx-state-tree

I've been learning MobX from the docs and wanted to replicate a normalized redux store in MobX.

I have a map of the authors `authorsMap` with the author's `id` as key and an array of authors' id, `authorsArray`, which is used to preserve order the authors are received from the server.

A computed property iterates over `authorsArray` and returns a new array with author objects.

Every time I add a new author to `authorsArray` and `auhorsMap`, my list component updates along with all the list items.

I've tried to figure it out from docs and I don't understand why it's happening, maybe I've missed something or maybe my expectations are wrong.

Here's the link to the sandbox
https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-clarke-u8ust?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Not quite understand what is your question? Why `AuthorList` updates? Because you iterate over all of the authors `authors.map(...` and `authors` is a computed property that gets updated after you add new author.

Comment: What you can and should do is mark `Author` component as `observer`. That way React won't re-render existing authors because they will be automatically `memo`d

Comment: Yes, `authors` is a computed array but the elements of `authors` are observable objects. Whenever a new author is added `authors` should be recomputed and `AuthorList` should be updated but the list items that are displaying individual author's information should not since they're observers and are observing on the observable objects present in `authors`, and `Author` is wrapped in `Observer` already.

Comment: `Author` is not wrapper in `observer` right now in your example. If you do that then it will work as expected.

Comment: `<Observer/>` don't have automatic memoization

Comment: If you don't use `memo` (or any alternative like `sCU` or whatever) then when Parent component re-renders all its children will re-render too.

Comment: Hmm, I guess `<Observer />` doesn't work the way I thought it would.